# How to make Sheety.co work inside the Vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, handlebars.js

The [Sheety API](https://sheety.co/) is great but I cannot make it work with Vue.

The only included example uses jQuery with handlebars.js which, like vue.js, uses double mustache syntax that collides.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>UK Theme Parks</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://api.sheety.co/uk-theme-parks', function(data) {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($('#item-template').html())
        $('#items').html(template(data))
    })
})
</script>
<script id="item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<ul>
    {{#each this}}
        <li><a href="{{website}}">{{name}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="items">Loading theme parks...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to make this example work inside the Vue component? Most preferably, to make it work without having to import the handlebars.js or jQuery?

Please mind that I am an exploratory designer, not a well-versed js coder, so I would greatly appreciate a working example :)